# Is it possible to get relation by parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For example I have model Class and model Pupil. Class -> hasMany[Pupil] and each Pupil -> belongsTo[Class].
Is it possible somehow with default Eloquent methods get all classes where pupil with name mike exists? I need to select this exactly from Class model.
P.S. Yes, i could add scope with joins, but i dont want to reinvent the wheel. May be some methods for this already exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to limit your results based on a relationship's contents:

```
App\Class::whereHas('pupil', function($q) {
  $q->whereName('Mike');
})->get();
```

Comment: it was my mistake downvoted you, I have removed my downvote and upvoted you. sorry dude, I was going through and found this unjustified downvote. sorry again

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ No worries. :-)